# How do timeline items get removed?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I was playing with the sample app for glass api - sent a bunch of items to my timeline, but now I cant figure out how to remove them?  Will they timeout on their own eventually?

Answer (score 6):

Philosophically, the timeline is not a collection that you're intended to manage like an email inbox. The idea is that as new cards come in, old cards fade into the past.

But, to get into the specifics, the cards will decay. They will no longer appear on your Glass after 7 days, and will decay from your timeline collection in the Mirror API after 30 days.

Some words of warning, though. This decay property isn't part of the API specification, and it's subject to change, do don't depend on this property for any of your development.

Answer (score 3):

[Send a REST `DELETE` operation to the timeline item URL](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/delete):

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/{id}
```

They will also expire after a while (currently 7 days on the client and 30 days on the server.)